# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection "missing pluggable transport"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, bridge, obfsproxy

I was using tor browser on my previous Windows XP installation without any problem, but after I installed Tor Browser version 4.0 on my fresh Windows XP-SP3 I can not connect to Tor network. I choose following in "Tor Network Setting" window: `Configure`-> `Does this computer need proxy... = No`-> `Does your ISP block... = Yes`-> `Connect with provided bridge = obfs3`-> `Connect`. I receive following error:

```
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
Connecting to a relay directory failed (missing pluggable transport).
```

If enter some bridges received from `bridges.torproject.org` and then press `Connect` I receive following error:

```
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
Loading network status failed (connection timeout).
```

Some times it takes about 5 minutes or so for the error dialog to be appeared. I do not know what is Tor Browser doing during these minutes.

I have no anti-virus installed on my Windows and disabled Windows FireWall.